# Flutter Switching to Tab Reloads Widgets and runs FutureBuilder

Tags: dart, flutter

The issue:

I have 2 tabs using Default Tabs Controller, like so:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        drawer: Menu(),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Container(
            child: Text('Dashboard'),
          ),
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text('Deals'),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text('Viewer'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            DealList(),
            ViewersPage(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The `DealList()` is a `StatefulWidget` which is built like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: this.loadDeals(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        print('Has error: ${snapshot.hasError}');
        print('Has data: ${snapshot.hasData}');
        print('Snapshot data: ${snapshot.data}');
        return snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done
            ? RefreshIndicator(
                onRefresh: showSomething,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: snapshot.data['deals'].length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final Map deal = snapshot.data['deals'][index];
                    print('A Deal: ${deal}');
                    return _getDealItem(deal, context);
                  },
                ),
              )
            : Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

With the above, here's what happens whenever I switch back to the `DealList()` tab: It reloads.

[image: Flutter]

Is there a way to prevent re-run of the FutureBuilder when done once? (the plan is for user to use the RefreshIndicator to reload. So changing tabs should not trigger anything, unless explicitly done so by user.)

Answer (score 145, accepted):

There are two issues here, the first:

When the `TabController` switches tabs, it unloads the old widget tree to save memory. If you want to change this behavior, you need to mixin [`AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html) to your tab widget's state.

```
class _DealListState extends State<DealList> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<DealList> {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context); // need to call super method.
    return /* ... */
  }
}
```

The second issue is in your use of the `FutureBuilder` -
If you provide a new `Future` to a `FutureBuilder`, it can't tell that the results would be the same as the last time, so it has to rebuild.  (Remember that Flutter may call your build method up to once a frame).

```
return FutureBuilder(
  future: this.loadDeals(), // Creates a new future on every build invocation.
  /* ... */
);
```

Instead, you want to assign the future to a member on your State class in initState, and then pass this value to the `FutureBuilder`.  The ensures that the future is the same on subsequent rebuilds.  If you want to force the State to reload the deals, you can always create a method which reassigns the `_loadingDeals` member and calls `setState`.

```
Future<...> _loadingDeals;

@override
void initState() {
  _loadingDeals = loadDeals(); // only create the future once.
  super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  super.build(context); // because we use the keep alive mixin.
  return new FutureBuilder(future: _loadingDeals, /* ... */);
}
```

Comment: In fact you killed two of my problems with one stone. Thanks so much. Really on point and the explanation makes sense, just like the solution does. Working now.

Comment: is there any solution without initState? Because I'm using streamBuilder with bloc pattern. all data fetch logic is inside my bloc class.

Comment: check this for  avoid initState, use 
 `AsyncMemoizer::runOnce() `
 https://medium.com/saugo360/flutter-my-futurebuilder-keeps-firing-6e774830bc2

Comment: I tried to implement this in my app, having `bottomNavigationBar`, but whenever I change page, it still fires the API.

Comment: Is it possible to get this working for max 3 tabs? The previous and the next one?

Comment: they could have at least provided a way to really prevent the tab from getting rebuilt. this solution still rebuilds the widget, but only runs the future once.

Comment: @Yeahia2508 did you find a solution for streamBluider ?

Comment: save my day, thank you 

also to @Fatimaayaa for streamBuilder is just same as i use streamBuilder

Comment: @SuroorAhmmad use IndexedStack when switching tab in bottomNavigatorBar. It does not rebuilt your widget. Like this ..     body: IndexedStack(
        index: currentIndex,
        children: [
          home(),
        ],
      ),